# Am I referencing this library wrong?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, github

This is the library I'm trying to use in my app: https://github.com/rampo/UpdateChecker

I downloaded the zip, unzipped it, imported it as an android project, marked it as a library, and added it to the list of libraries by going into the properties of my app folder. I am getting this error:

```
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\jake\Downloads\UpdateChecker-master\UpdateChecker-master\library\src\main\bin\updatechecker.jar'
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using eclipse btw.

Comment: 1) Did UpdateChecker compile without errors 2) tried cleaning all projects?

Comment: Eclipse isn't showing any problems for UpdateChecker under the "problems" tab. It's only showing 2 problems for my actual app and one is listed above and the other is "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved". I tried cleaning the projects.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to install gradle on you machine and build the project, see: http://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/ you might have to add the jar section described in the link, not sure though (not much gradle experience here)

Comment: Is there any alternative to using Gradle? I have 0 experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to use that library? (Not editing source) if so, you can copy that .jar file into the 'libs' folder inside your project

C:\path\to\workspace\myProject\libs

Comment: That's the thing though, this project didn't come with a jar. What am I supposed to do @aquiros

Comment: Import the UpdateChecker project to your eclipse workspace, then in your project import UpdateChecker to the buildpath and move it to the top of the list, also checking the checkbox. @user3648245